# Changing appearance of SearchBar Table View

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I have a search bar that draws on top of a table. I also have a text field above that search bar. I want the table view in which the search bar's results are displayed to appear below the search bar and not cover the text field.

This is what I have tried -

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 400);
}
```

This makes the table appear below the search bar, but after I type I can't enter anything into the text field(I think because it's being covered).

I then tried taking out the search display controller and using a table view - I pointed the delegate and dataSource of the table view to the view controller, but the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not being called.

How do I achieve what I want?

[image]

This is what it looks like in interface builder.

When I click on the search bar this is what happens -

[image]

When I click on the search bar - this is what it looks like. It seems to me there is a table view appearing on top of my search text field. After I make this go away by clicking on a table cell I can't click on the search button or add any text to the text field. So, I want to move this table view to be below the search bar.

Comment: Put the search bar in tableview header.

Comment: Drag and drop UISearchBar in top of the UITableView in xib file.

Comment: there is no uiTableView in the xib file - the table view is coming from searchDisplayController.tableView

Comment: Add an UITableView in interface builder and connect it with IBOutlet in .h file. Then use it in your code as such 


- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [_tableView reloadData];
}